# Getting wrong description on WCF client side for a WCF method

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0

I am getting the wrong definition on my client side for my WCF method.

Here is my WCF method implementation where I am getting a employee request classes' object and returning an `EmployeeInfo` object

```
public EmployeeInfo GetEmployee(EmployeeRequest request)
{
        Employee employee = null;

        try
        {               
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getEmployee", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", request.EmployeeId);

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    if ((EmployeeType)reader["EmployeeType"] == EmployeeType.FullTimeEmployee)
                    {
                        employee = new FullTimeEmployee
                        {
                        Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]),
                        Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
                        Sex = reader["Gender"].ToString(),
                        DateOfJoining = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateOfBirth"]),
                        Type=EmployeeType.FullTimeEmployee,
                        AnnualSalary=Convert.ToInt32(reader["AnnualSalary"])
                        };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        employee = new PartTimeEmployee
                        {
                            Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]),
                            Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
                            Sex = reader["Gender"].ToString(),
                            DateOfJoining = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateOfBirth"]),
                            Type = EmployeeType.PartTimeEmployee,
                            HourlyPay = Convert.ToInt32(reader["HourlyPay"]),
                            HourlyWoked= Convert.ToInt32(reader["HoursWorked"])
                        };
                    }
                }

                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }

        info = (new EmployeeInfo(employee));
        return info;
}
```

Here are my `EmployeeInfo` and `EmployeeRequest` classes:

```
public class EmployeeRequest
{
    [MessageHeader(Namespace = "http://MyCompanyDomain.com/Employee")]
    public string LicenceKey { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://MyCompanyDomain.com/Employee")]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeInfo
{
    public EmployeeInfo(Employee employee)
    {
        this.Id = employee.Id;
        this.Name = employee.Name;
        this.Sex = employee.Sex;
        this.DateOfJoining = employee.DateOfJoining;
        this.Type = (EmployeeType)employee.Type;

        if (this.Type == EmployeeType.FullTimeEmployee)
        {
            this.AnnualSalary = ((FullTimeEmployee)employee).AnnualSalary;
        }
        else
        {
            this.HourlyPay = ((PartTimeEmployee)employee).HourlyPay;
            this.HourlyWorked = ((PartTimeEmployee)employee).HourlyWorked;
        }
    }

    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://MyCompanyDomain.com/Employee")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://MyCompanyDomain.com/Employee")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://MyCompanyDomain.com/Employee")]
    public string Sex { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://MyCompanyDomain.com/Employee")]
    public DateTime DateOfJoining { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://MyCompanyDomain.com/Employee")]
    public EmployeeType Type { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://MyCompanyDomain.com/Employee")]
    public int AnnualSalary { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://MyCompanyDomain.com/Employee")]
    public int HourlyPay { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://MyCompanyDomain.com/Employee")]
    public int HourlyWorked { get; set; }
}
```

Now as you can see in the below screenshot, I am getting the parameters instead of the whole object on my client side.

[image]

Comment: Do Clean Solution, then do ReBuild...

Comment: I have already tried it Even I have created the new project with same code and port number but the error remains same every time